# Do things called in .then of a $q promise chain get applied in a digest?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

If I use Angular's $q, do I have to worry about using $evalAsyn or $apply? Or is that handled automatically by $q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, you don't need to worry about the $digest/$apply/$evalSync things in angular. According to [$q document here,](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

There is a short comparison:

#### Differences between Kris Kowal's Q and $q

There are two main differences:

- $q is **integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in angular**, which means faster propagation of resolution or rejection into your models and avoiding unnecessary browser repaints, which would result in flickering UI.
- Q has many more features than $q, but that comes at a cost of bytes. $q is tiny, but contains all the important functionality needed for common async tasks.

[Here is the source code in $q.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L219)

```
this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$exceptionHandler', function($rootScope, $exceptionHandler) {
    return qFactory(function(callback) { //invoke qFactory
      $rootScope.$evalAsync(callback); //$evalAsync here...
    }, $exceptionHandler);
}];
function $$QProvider() {
  this.$get = ['$browser', '$exceptionHandler', function($browser, $exceptionHandler) {
    return qFactory(function(callback) {
      $browser.defer(callback);
    }, $exceptionHandler);
  }];
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So if I make a new $q promise `myPromise`, then `setTimeout(function(){myPromise().then(function() {...})})` the code in the callback passed to `then` will be `$evalAsync`ed?

Comment: @trusktr According to the document. It seems it will works like this. So I write [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/x7uev2s2/1/) to test, it works.